# Weighted sample and logistic regression

Tags: logistic, spss, sample

I am doing logistic regression in which I have a weighted sample data. Should I should have the weight option on or off when doing logistic regression?

Comment: Could you tell us what programming language/software you are using?

Comment: Apparently it's SPSS.

Comment: Haha, I missed the tag, right you are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have weights, as well as strata and clusters/PSU in the Complex Design add-on.